# I Can't Change label.text with Timer in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, label

```
@IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!
var timer = Timer()

let now = Date()
let userCalendar = Calendar.current
let formatter = DateFormatter()

func printTime() {

    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh/mm/ss a"
    let startTime = now
    let endTime = formatter.date(from: "01/01/17 00/00/00 a")

    let difference = userCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .year, .hour, .minute, .second], from: startTime, to: endTime!)

    timeLabel.text = "Yılbaşına \(difference.month!) ay, \(difference.day!) gün, \(difference.hour!) saat, \(difference.minute!) dakika, \(difference.second!) saniye kaldı"

    print("hello world")

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(ViewController.printTime),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[When it is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIsWw.png)

I am using Xcode 8 with Swift 3. When I run this code it is writes to console "hello world" every second but it is not update label when timer is running. I want to countdown for label for every second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.after(when: .now() + 1.0) { //after one second
    timeLabel.text = "Yılbaşına \(difference.month!) ay, \(difference.day!) gün, \(difference.hour!) saat, \(difference.minute!) dakika, \(difference.second!) saniye kaldı"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved. First I delete "let now = Date()" line and I changed "let startTime = Date()